# Google Maps Api Loading But Not Displaying

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had the map on this page working for months. Now the map loads but does not display. I can tell this because the api is adding code. But the end result is white space in the map div. Some help would be appritiated. Below is the java script and html code:

```
/**********************************************************/
/*   JS Google Map                                        */
/**********************************************************/
function initMap() {
    var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(36.828800, -76.132800);

        var draggableValue;
        if($(document).width() <= 768){
            draggableValue = false;   
        }
        else{
            draggableValue = true;   
        }


    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLocation,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeControl: true, 
        draggable: draggableValue,
        scaleControl: false,   
        scrollwheel: false,   
       styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#555559" },
            {lightness: 51}
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#555559" }
        ]
    },{
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "weight": 8 },
            { "hue": "#ffffff" },
            { "color": "#ffffff" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#ffffff" },
            { "visibility": "on" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" },
            { "color": "#ffffff" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#ffffff" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "water",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#555559" },
            {lightness: 25}
        ]
    },{
    },{"stylers": [{"saturation": 0}]}
],

        streetViewControl: true   /**/

    };

     var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/assets/images/icon.png',
            new google.maps.Size(500, 500),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(30, 30),
            new google.maps.Size(60, 60)
        );
    var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 60, 60, 60, 60, 1],
        type: 'poly'
        };
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 30),
        content: '<h5 class="map-header text-center">Header</h5><p class="text-center">Info window text</p>'
        });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLocation,
        icon: image,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -60),
        title: 'Header'
        });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }); 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

/**********************************************************/
/*   HTML Google Map                                      */
/**********************************************************/
<section style="height:100%;">
        <div class="map" id="map">
        </div>
</section>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81qtzz1n/).

Comment: Your fiddle is not configured correctly (you are using jQuery, but don't include it, you are including a non-secure version of the API on a secure jsfiddle, your code is set up to run onload, but is expecting to be in the global namespace...)

Comment: Might be related to [Issue 10449:Bug: maps not showing, no console errors](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10449)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `min-height` with `height`.

Here's the working demo: http://jsbin.com/heposuwipu/edit?html,css,js,output

The same issue happened to me today. Seems like GoogleMaps API changed today and the map won't show if the min-height is set. Since the `min-heigh` behaves as the `height` in your example, it's safe to replace `min-height` with `height`.

P.S. You had other problems on your JSFiddle demo that prevented the map from appearing. I think that jQuery and GoogleMaps javascript file were not loaded correctly so I've created another demo on JSBin.

**Update:** Google Maps API just rolled back the today's update so `min-height` will work as before (https://twitter.com/GoogleMapsAPI/status/773650227123277824). Thanks @geocodezip for providing the link to the issue to track.

Comment: Awesome. This worked like a charm. Thanks! I couldn't figure this out for the life of me. Yea, I just know realized the Google Maps wasn't loaded right in the JSFiddle, but the page that I'm actually implementing the map on has the script loaded correctly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.

Have you seen [Google Maps - Not displaying but loaded in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236025/google-maps-not-displaying-but-loaded-in-html) ?

Try style the div for map with height 100%:

```
    <section style="height:100%;">
        <div class="map" id="map" style="height:100%;">
        </div>
    </section>
```